# horizontal motion inside a cone (cylindrical polars)

Tags: classical-mechanics

I have a question from an example we done in lecture

Suppose we have a particle moving inside the surface of a cone given by $r = wz$ where $w$ is a constant,

and also suppose initially the particle is moving horizontally at height $b$ and speed $U$,the lecturer then stated these "facts"

$\underline{\dot r} = U \underline{e_\theta}$ so $\dot r = 0$, $\dot z = 0$

I understand where he got $\underline{\dot r} = U \underline{e_\theta}$, however, I do not understand why $\dot r = 0$ and $ \dot z = 0$, all we know is that $z(0) = b$, and $\dot r(0) = U$, but that does not mean general $\dot z, \dot r$ are $0$,

if someone could clear this up please

edit: [image: a] !

Comment: Are you sure you copied those initial conditions correctly? They don't make sense to me (eg $\dot r(0) = U$ should (?) be $ \dot r(0) = 0$. $\dot z$ and $\dot r$ *can* be zero always depending on the values of b and U. Can you clarify what the question of the problem is?

Comment: @kvothe I have edited my question with an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It says "*initially*, $\dot r = \dot z = 0$". This is synonymous with $\dot r(0) = \dot z(0) = 0$. Vague wording like that is usually to trick students.

Comment: but I'm asking how did he get that result? if r(0) = b = constant it doesn't mean $\dot r(0) = 0$

Comment: It's vertical speed ( = $\dot z$) at t = 0 is zero. And $r$ and $z$ are dependent on each other and according to the boundary condition, $ \dot r(0)= 0$ as well.

Answer (score -1):

You've missed the phrase "and is moving horizontally". Since the cone is oriented vertically, the particle will continue moving horizontally, that is, in a horizontal circle. Its height z will remain constant, and its radius r will also remain constant.